# Preview is bolt cms is different from a published post

Tags: css, bolt-cms

The preview of a page is different from how it looks when you publish the same page. When I preview it, the the text on the page is all messed up but when I publish it the page looks as it should. Is there any way I can correct this?

Comment: Might have something to do with caching? Have you previewed with a refresh that bypasses cache?

Answer (score 1):

When you refresh your page, afterwared upading content.

Must be press  CTRL + F5

```
CTRL + F5
```

is fetch page directly from server, and skip cache.